# a spring kafka consumer with multiple brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm currently implementing kafka listener with spring kafka.
And now I'm little bit because my listener sometimes could not be assigned to partition so could not receive any message from one of the brokers.

#### current situation

I have two brokers and each broker has one topic which includes only one partition.(topic name is same)

| broker1 | broker2 |
| --- | --- |
| Topic1 | Topic1 |
| one partition | one partition |

Maybe I'm having wrong idea for setting my kafka listener to take messages from both two brokers. However, is following sentence proper guess?

Are `Passing two brokers' host to listener` and `Setting concurrency to 2` enough config because I have two partitions (one in broker1 and other one in broker2)?

#### what I did

create a listener with annotation

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "$Topic1" , containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
```

set its concurrency to `2`

```java
factory.setConcurrency(2);
```

give array of brokers

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, [123.123.123:9092, 211.211.211:9094]);
```

set group

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testgroup");
```

set partition assignment strategy with round robin way

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RoundRobinAssignor.class.getName());
```

#### what I expected

being able to receive messages from both brokers but sometimes could not get any message from one of two brokers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the brokers are in the same cluster it should work OK.

If the brokers are not part of the same cluster, you must add two `@KafkaListener` annotations, each one using a container factory that points to each cluster. Or, you can use the `properties` attribute on one of the annotations to override the `ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` property.

Comment: Yes Both brokers are in the same cluster.  

So, one `KafkaListener` should be sufficient for this case.  

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.